# Store object array into Arraylist

Tags: java

I have an array of objects named x (that is Object[] x).

When I call x[0], it give me a bunch of (double) numbers, like:

```
1.111
1.344
433.22...
```

How could I store these numbers into a new ArrayList? Thanks.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: So you have arrays in your array ?

Comment: You mean you want to take the numbers in the array and put them into a list, or you want a list of arrays? There's always Arrays.asList.

Comment: I dont know, x is the output from Javabuilder ja (matlab code run in java).

Comment: @Dave : i wanna get these numbers (from x[0]) and store them in a new Arraylist.

Comment: @NguyenHoaiThanh So, as DNA points out, and as my comment said, there's Arrays.asList. Even if there wasn't, wouldn't writing a simple loop over the array and adding them to a new ArrayList work? Showing some effort will tend to produce more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
List list = Arrays.asList(x[0]);
```

Doesn't guarantee that the `List` is an `ArrayList`, but that probably doesn't matter (in fact, it *is* an ArrayList, if you look at the JDK source).